# Would this be good solution to providing Image sources in React Native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

So in javascript, you cant use dynamic variables as a part of the path for `require()` right?. Well i have a bunch of images that are displayed dynamically/conditionally based on user actions so I can't really just have all of the paths explicitly written in the main code somewhere. So i was thinking would it be a good idea to create a javascript object in another file of the format

`{icon_1: require("../some/path.file"), ...}`

and then import the object and I would just put `source={obj.icon_1}` for an image source or whatever. Would this cause performance issues? There is easily going to be over 400 images. Is there an easier way to do this other than using cloud storage and just using the url (that is my last resort)

Comment: Did you try it?  It's just JavaScript.  There's nothing special that says the argument to `require` has to be a string literal.

Comment: @Wyck yes ive tried it. For example if i do 
```
var obj = { one: "image1.png", two: "image2.png" };
data.image = require(`../assets/${obj.one}`);
```
I will get an error. I probably worded it wrong in the post but that's what i meant

Comment: Works fine for me.  Can you post the error message?